# How to count character and line from a string in assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

I want to write the corresponding assembly code of the UNiX/LINUX command `wc`
This code is just for test.

```
global main
extern printf

section .data
fmt:
    db "%ld %ld",10,0
msg:
    db 'CSE DU',10,'Dhaka',10,'Bangladesh',0
    ;db 'CSE DU',10,0
section .text
main:
    push rbp

    mov rcx , 0 ; rcx = number of charecter
    mov rbx , 0 ; rbx = number of line
lp:

    mov rax , [msg+rcx]
    inc rcx
    cmp rax , 0
    je exit ; jump if rax = 0 means EOF ; break
    cmp rax , 10
    jne lp ; jump if rax != 10 means not new line
    inc rbx ; increment rbx if new line found
    jmp lp ; continue

exit:
    dec rcx
    mov rdi , fmt
    mov rsi , rbx
    mov rdx ,rcx
    call printf

    pop rbp
    ret
```

The result of this code is `0 23` but the correct result is `2 23`.

If i use `msg: db 'CSE DU',10,0`(which is comment out in the code) then the result is correct and result is `1 7`

I have searched in google but didn't get any solution for my platform.
I am using Ubuntu(Linux), my machine is 64-bit, the assembler is NASM and use the c printf functin.

I spent many time but didn't detect the problem. If anybody detect please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When reading characters, they are only 8 bits wide, so only read and compare 8 bit values

```
     mov     al, [msg+rcx]
     inc    rcx
     cmp     al, 0
     je     exit
     cmp     al, 10
     jne    lp
     inc    rbx
     jmp    lp
```

Comment: Yes, either use `al` like this says, or, in other cases where you need it to be widened, use `movzx` to zero-extend the value to a 64 bit value. The `mov rax,[msg+rcx]` is reading eight bytes, not one byte.